# Find the inverse function of $f$. How do I isolate the $y$ if $f(x)= x/(x+4)$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Find the inverse function of $f$.

How do I isolate the $y$ if $ f(x) = x/(x+4)$?

I am stuck at $(y+4)x = y$.

I can't divide both sides by $y$. I am stumped.

Answer (score 2):

$$(y+4)x=y\\
\implies xy+4x=y\\
\implies y(x-1)=-4x\\
\implies y=\dfrac{-4x}{x-1}$$

Comment: still lost. After you transferred the y to the left hand side. How did you get y(x-1)?

Comment: I see it now. Thanks!

Comment: $$xy+4x=y\\ \implies xy-y=4x\\ \implies x(y-1)=4x$$

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track.  Expand $(y+4)x$ out to get $yx+4x=y$.  Subtracting $y$ on both sides gives us $yx-y+4x=0$.  Then $y(x-1)=-4x$, so that $y=\frac{-4x}{x-1}$.

Comment: You beat me by $12$ seconds! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Domain and codomain of $f$? Say that  $f:\mathbb{R}\setminus \{-4\}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}\setminus \{1\}$, $\displaystyle f(x)=\frac{x}{x+4}$.

First, for $f$ to be invertible, we need to show that it is a bijection:

(1) $f$ is injective: Indeed,
$$f(a)=f(b)\Rightarrow \frac{a}{a+4}=\frac{b}{b+4}\Rightarrow a(b+4)=b(a+4)\Rightarrow ...\Rightarrow a=b. $$

Then, $f$ is injective.

(2) $f$ is surjective: indeed, $\forall z\in \mathbb{R}\setminus \{1\}$, $\exists x\in \mathbb{R}\setminus \{-4\}$ such that $f(x)=z$. 
In fact, just take $\displaystyle x=\frac{4z}{1-z}$:
$$f(x) =f(\frac{4z}{1-z})=\frac{\displaystyle\frac{4z}{1-z}}{\displaystyle \frac{4z}{1-z}+4}=...=z.$$
Then, $f$ is surjective.

Then, $f$ is bijective and so, $f$ is invertible.

Then, $\exists f^{-1}:\mathbb{R}\setminus \{1\}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}\setminus \{-4\}$ given by
$$f^{-1}(y)=\frac{4y}{1-y}. $$

Comment: I hope to be at the level that you are at one day. Hope springs eternal.